# python api automation / getting status code = 500 and {Message ":"An error has occured."}

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest

```
import requests
import json
import jsonpath

def test_add_new_data():
    # url = "http://thetestingworldapi.com/api/studentsDetails"
    # f = open('/Users/sunghunkwak/PycharmProjects/apiTesting/postStudent.json', 'r')
    # requests_post_id = json.loads(f.read())
    # result = requests.post(url, requests_post_id)
    # assert result.status_code == 201
    # id = jsonpath.jsonpath(result.json(), 'id')
    # print(id[0])

    url_tech = "http://thetestingworldapi.com/api/technicalskills"
    f = open('/Users/sunghunkwak/PycharmProjects/apiTesting/postTechskills.json', 'r')
    requests_post_tech = json.loads(f.read())
    result = requests.post(url_tech, requests_post_tech)
    assert result.status_code == 200
    print(result.text)

    url_addr = "http://thetestingworldapi.com/api/addresses"
    f = open('/Users/sunghunkwak/PycharmProjects/apiTesting/postAddress.json', 'r')
    requests_post_addr = json.loads(f.read())
    result = requests.post(url_addr, requests_post_addr)
    print(result.status_code)
    # assert result.status_code == 200

    url_final = "http://thetestingworldapi.com/api/FinalStudentDetails/189969"
    requests_get = requests.get(url_final)
    print(requests_get.text)
```

I tried to test, but it keeps getting errors like below.

test.py {"status":"true","msg":"Add  data success"}
500
{"Message":"An error has occurred."}

post address and get final data are getting errors.
How can I solve it??
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your JSON files are correct that you're trying to post? Here is an example post request:

```
import requests

url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users'
payload = {
    "name": "foo",
    "job": "bar"
}

x = requests.post(url, data=payload)

print(x.text)
```

When I tried to change the "URL" the URL to "http://thetestingworldapi.com/api/addresses" also throws the same error `{"Message":"An error has occurred."}`

Here is an another example I read it from JSON file and requested:

```
import requests
import os
import json

url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users'

filename = "foo.json"
folder_ = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
absolute_filename = os.path.join(folder_, filename)
f = open(absolute_filename, 'r')
payload = json.loads(f.read())
x = requests.post(url, payload)

print(x.text)
```

Looks like you have an error in server side.
Also I suggest you read HTTP response status codes:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Comment: Hi, I used the correct JSON file to post. post student and post techskills work, but the other two do not work. Do you mean the server has problem, so I cannot solve it?

Comment: It looks like server has a problem or you represent a wrong JSON format.